# compute the homology groups

Tags: algebraic-topology

Consider the complex $M$, which is the union of three triangles $v_1v_2v_5, v_1v_5v_4, v_4v_5v_3$ and the line segment $v_2v_3$. Compute the homology groups $H_1(M)$ and $H_2(M)$.

Is $H_1(M)\simeq\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$, and is $H_2(M)$ trivial? More precisely, is $Z_1(M)\simeq\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ and $B_1(M)\simeq\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$, and is $Z_2(M)$ trivial?

Comment: you mean to say three triangle connected by a line segment or what?? your space is not clear to me

Comment: It is the exercise 1.5.2. from Munkres' Elements of Algebraic Topology, if that helps.

Comment: I dont have that book

Comment: I've edited the op. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of your space is correct. It is simply a graph. From this we can form the chain complex:

$$ 0 \to C_1 \xrightarrow{\partial} C_0 \to 0$$

where $C_0$ the the free module generated by the vertices $v_0, \dots v_5$ and $C_1$ is the free module generated by the 8 edges.

The boundary matrix $\partial$ is of rank $4$, and so on taking homology groups we can see $H_0 = \mathbb{Z}$, $H_1 = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$, and all other homology groups are trivial.

A less hands on approach is to draw the graph and notice that it is homotopy equivalent to the wedge product of 4 circles.

Comment: I think it's supposed to be three 2-simplices ("triangles") with a line segment between them (hence their calculation that $B_1=\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus 3}$).  Then $H_1=\mathbb{Z}$.  The space is homotopy equivalent to an $S^1$ by collapsing the contractible subcomplex formed by the triangles.